# Suddenly getting this SVN error

Tags: svn, command-line, notepad++

Why the hell would I suddenly be getting this svn error when I try to import files into my repo? What does it even have to do with notepad++?

Thanks :)

> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\lab>svn
>   import c:/wordpress
>   http://tasty.unfuddle.com/svn/tasty_lab/wordpress
>   'C:\Program' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. svn:
>   system('C:\Program
>   Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
>   svn-commit.tmp') returned 1

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was able to get this working by adding the -m to my command :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

svn is trying to open your default editor to let you enter a commit message, and fails. I have no idea how to alter the default editor in Windows (in linux it would be something like `export EDITOR=/path/to/editor`.

Until someone explains how to alter your default editor, you can circumvent this temporarily by either entering the comment directly with `-m'Comment'`, or providing `--editor-cmd`

Comment: OOOOH. So basically I'm leaving off my -m!

Answer (score 6):

Use short path for your %EDITOR% environment variable. That should fix the problem.

```
set EDITOR=C:\Progra~1\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

Or to make the change permanent..

On Windows Vista and up:

```
setx EDITOR C:\Progra~1\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

On older versions you'll have to use the GUI:

- Right-click *My Computer*
- From the context menu select *properties*
- Go to advanced system settings
- Click on the *Environment variables* button
- Change the value of EDITOR there

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the complete answer, but the reason it's returning a Notepad++ error is because that's your default text editor. SVN is trying to open that up so you can write a log message, but failing, presumably because it's choking on the space in "Program Files". Try fixing the global environment variable for your default text editor. I forget what it's called, but it shouldn't be hard to find.

If you need a quick hack to allow you to import so you aren't blocked *right now*, then run `svn import -m "Logging Message Goes Here" C:/files/I/want/to/import`